# Session State with MVC Confusion

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've worked on several .coms and we've never used the built-in ASP.NET session state.  It has always been check a cookie for a valid session checks and the session is compared to what's in the DB or other means but ultimately it's the cookie.  We haven't used any ASP.NET based session objects.

So why are people using all this session state server crap with MVC?  I have never seen a need for it.

Comment: Can't say I've seen MVC & session mentioned together, but then I haven't looked. I haven't used session state in a long time & would agree with you. Useful to have it though, and switch it off, because, you know, maybe one day, who knows.

Comment: I avoid session state whenever possible as well, but aren't there some times when it is useful? For example, how would you do this without using Session state: "Track the last 20 products the user has viewed. In a side bar widget, display recommendations for similar products based on the 20 most recently viewed products.". Is there a way to do this without session state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have never seen a need for it.

Me too. I never use ASP.NET session state in my web applications. I prefer designing them in a RESTful manner rather than introducing state. One of the very first things I do in any web application is to add the following line in web.config to ensure that any future developers don't make the mistake of using session:

```
<sessionState mode="Off" />
```

I guess people are using it to simplify the storage of some volatile data across multiple requests.

Comment: yea see this is what is confusing to me.  I have worked on serveral .coms, not once did we use the built-in asp.net session objects.  And yet I still see SOME people resorting to the only thing they know in MVC apps which is to use IMO a heavy session state object/framework which is not needed.  YOu just need forms auth ticket and cookie...

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET does have a SQL backed session state indexed by session ID which is checked against the cookie's session ID. ASP.NET also allows you to store the session in-memory (default). The same building blocks are available in MVC.

Essentially what you've implemented ("always been check a cookie for a valid session checks and the session is compared to what's in the DB or other means but ultimately it's the cookie.") is exactly what you're pooh poohing! Doesn't make sense to reinvent the wheel ...

As to the specific *use case*, you can use it to handle any state that needs to persist. In your specific case, just check why you store the cookie and lookup the database - that's exactly where you would use session state (to SQL or to memory)

Comment: I so agree. I think people bad-mouth session state because some other people have abused it, historically. Uses cases are easy to find, and when you need it, there's no need to reinvent it like OP does.

Answer (score 0):

How do you handle the need for session timeouts for no activity?  Cookies are only not very secure.

Comment: I think the OP's saying no session, no session timeout to worry about as the app isn't session aware. If you mean authentication timeout then auth cookie takes care of that. You'll need to explain what you mean by "Cookies are only not very secure"

Comment: Cookies are not 100% safe, nothing is.  How you defined against that is you check for IP in the incoming request and compare it to what's in your auth cookie...if they match, you know nobody has hacked your cookie session. But this cookies is not safe thing is a statement that doesn't have any bearing because I've seen 5 .coms use cookies and that is the norm and preferred way to go in e-commerce or any public website if you know what you're doing.  It seems to me the people who use this session state provided by MS have never experiened a true .com or high traffic site & pro way to do this